# jQuery toggle show/hide - div does not expand

Tags: show-hide, jquery

I have a little menu that should expand to reveal the HTML below, which is hidden at present.

Following jQuery:

```
$('.mobileMenu').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('arrowDown').next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

This piece of code works great on [this page](http://www.haselden.co.uk/rttest/inner.html) (click the "hide" feature on the left col)

However I need to utilise the same feature with my menu for "mobile width".

If you resize your browser down to 320 or so and go [here](http://www.haselden.co.uk/rttest/index.html) you'll see the menu is just +menu (bit smashy at the mo but working). Click it, and the menu does expand to show the links, but they are hanging over the `main` content area.

All divs in the `navigation` div are `display:block` but they still don't push the `main` div down. I want the entire green `navigation` div to expand with it's content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a fixed height on the `navigation` div of `60px` and `menuWrapper` at `30px`. You need to make this relative.

Answer (score 0):

change your css from

```
#rightCol {
width: 72.5%;
float:right;
}

#leftCol
{
width: 25%;
float:left;
}
```

to

```
#rightCol {
width: 72.5%;
display:inline-block;
}

#leftCol
{
width: 25%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

it should work. I have tested this on chrome